# My text to speech doesn't want to talk back to me

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am still having problems with my TextToSpeech android,  I entered the button twice once for the implemented Speech like exlipse asked me too and one for the implemented OnClickListener,  Even if I take out the bottom action for the button it doesn't want to play, Why? idk it just doesn't want to say what is in my EditText Field I have no clue why it doesn't want to and I have asked around many times but I haven't goten an answer that worked.

```
package com.write.it;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Speech extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener, OnClickListener {
private EditText words = null;
private Button speakBtn = null;
private static final int REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK = 0;
private static final String TAG = "TTS Demo";
private TextToSpeech mTts;

private int uttCount = 0;
private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    words = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.wordsToSpeak);
    speakBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.speak);


    // Check to be sure that TTS exists and is okay to use
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK);
}


public void doSpeak(View view) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(words.getText().toString(),",.");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
                String.valueOf(uttCount++));
        mTts.speak(st.nextToken(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
     }

    speakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.speak:
                doSpeak(v);
                break;
            }
        }
});
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQ_TTS_STATUS_CHECK) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS:
            // TTS is up and running
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            Log.v(TAG, "Pico is installed okay");
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_BAD_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_DATA:
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_MISSING_VOLUME:
            // missing data, install it
            Log.v(TAG, "Need language stuff: " + resultCode);
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_FAIL:
        default:
            Log.e(TAG, "Got a failure. TTS not available");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Got something else
    }
}

public void onInit(int status) {
    // Now that the TTS engine is ready, we enable the button
    if( status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
        speakBtn.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // if we're losing focus, stop talking
    if( mTts != null)
        mTts.stop();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mTts.shutdown();
}

public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Got completed message for uttId: " + uttId);
    Integer.parseInt(uttId);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.speak:
        doSpeak(v);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try speaking the text with just one method call? Like this

```
mTts.speak(aString, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

It works fine for me. The initialization I use is the same as yours. The only remaining difference is this (which should not be necessary to get the TTS to work!):

```
        this.speaker.setSpeechRate(0.9f);
        this.speaker.setPitch(0.9f);
```

Comment: ok im going to try what you wrote thank yout for your answer, and I will let you know if it works

Comment: I added this mTts.speak to the doSpeal() method I just wanted to be sure if that is the correct area? and it still didnt work... I really dont know what is going on...